# RVM not compiling ruby 1.9.3

Tags: compilation, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I'm having an issue with RVM that I haven't seen before. I'm trying to install ruby 1.9.3 but it installs a binary version instead of compiling:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #validate archive
tar: Record size = 8 blocks
tar: Record size = 8 blocks
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #validate binary
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #setup
Saving wrappers to '/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time ...
```

Then if I try

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ ruby -v
$ ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [i686-linux]
```

However, there are no sources:

```
 $ ls .rvm/src/
 ruby-1.8.7-p371  rubygems-1.8.24  rvm  yaml-0.1.4
```

Is there any reason why RVM is not compiling ruby 1.9.3?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Compiling ruby takes time, RVM provides binary rubies so Ruby can be installed faster and that no compilations errors break installation.

You could check `rvm help install` where first line is:

> ### Usage
>
> ```
> rvm install {ruby-string} [--verify-download {0,1,2}] [--binary|--disable-binary|--movable]
> ```

so it's enough to use:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary
```

but if you only need sources then run:

```
rvm fetch 1.9.3
```